# Android Activity Recreation Scenarios other than Screen Rotation

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel

I am trying to understand if using the ViewModel (MVVM) will be helpful if orientation of my Activity is always going to be portrait. What are other scenarios which will recreate an Activity other than screen rotation?

Comment: Screen rotation is just so small part of MVVM. I am missing your point.

Comment: One of the cases if you put you app in backgound (using home button) and not to remove it from recent apps list your app will be alive for some time until the system kill it and if you open your app from recents after it was killed you'll get a new instance of activity but it'll have a not null bundle on it's onCreate() method and actually in this case your app should continue working from exact same state when it was moved to background.

Comment: @YavorMitev I just need scenarios/cases, other than screen-rotation, where ViewModel survives the Activity recreation.

Comment: @easy_breezy You are talking about process-death, and ViewModels do not survive process-death.

Comment: My point is - ok, if the use case is only screen rotation, and you are always in portrait mode - why on Earth would you not use ViewModels? What else would you use and why do you think it would have a single benefit over ViewModels?

Comment: @YavorMitev Currently we are using MVC pattern and thinking of moving to MVVM, so I wanted to know the benefits of ViewModel other than surviving screen-rotations.

Comment: Why didn't you try with: "Currently we are using MVC pattern and thinking of moving to MVVM, so I wanted to know the benefits of MVVM over MVC"? You are assuming why it is used and pointing people here in the wrong direction. Please read what are the requirements for a question. Part of it is showing some research and effort. Here is none.

Comment: @YavorMitev No, this is NOT an MVC vs MVVM discussion. My question is specifically about the ViewModel. In every article that I have read about advantages of ViewModel, the only example I see is that of screen-rotation.

Comment: You can not analyze ViewModel without MVVM. Out of box it can been shared between fragments in the same activity. I am not sure what is your implementation of MVC, but it is something you need to support. Here it is out of the box. Also, you have ViewModel scope which easily supports coroutines. It works well with Dagger/Hilt and LiveData.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rotating your screen is just an example of activity recreation due to configuration change.

Any other configuration change can cause activity recreation. Another example is language change.

For more info about runtime configuration change, read:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes

This is the full list of the configurations that can recreate activity (orientation refers to screen rotation):

```
["mcc", "mnc", "locale"  "touchscreen", "keyboard", "keyboardHidden",, "navigation", "screenLayout", "fontScale", "uiMode", "orientation", "density", "screenSize", "smallestScreenSize"]
```

Taken from:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#config

Comment: Thanks, I was able to test the Activity recreation by changing the language.

Comment: Nice to hear :). I also learned a thing or two answering this one.